# Microsoft VC++, vsnprintf, and Pipes (IO) Bug

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, named-pipes, dll-injection

I am using a DLL injection on to start the client end of a file pipe, which talks to a server that logs the messages. The problem is that the server only receives a buffer filled with question mark ('?') characters.

Client / Injectable DLL:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024*1024

HANDLE hPipe;
BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE;
DWORD  cbToWrite, cbWritten, dwMode;
const wchar_t* lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\listen");
char write_buffer[BUFSIZE];

void init()
{
    hPipe = CreateFile(
        lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
        GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,              // no sharing 
        NULL,           // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
        0,              // default attributes 
        NULL);          // no template file 

// The pipe connected; change to message-read mode. 

    dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
    fSuccess = SetNamedPipeHandleState(
        hPipe,    // pipe handle 
        &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
        NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
        NULL);    // don't set maximum time 
}
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
void report(const char* frmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, frmt);
    vsnprintf(write_buffer, BUFSIZE, frmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    // Send a message to the pipe server. 

    fSuccess = WriteFile(
        hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
        write_buffer,             // message 
        strlen(write_buffer),              // message length 
        &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
        NULL);                  // not overlapped 

    return;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024*1024

BOOL   fConnected = FALSE;
DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL;
const wchar_t* lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\listen");

// The main loop creates an instance of the named pipe and 
// then waits for a client to connect to it. When the client 
// connects, a thread is created to handle communications 
// with that client, and this loop is free to wait for the
// next client connect request. It is an infinite loop.

for (;;)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n"), lpszPipename);
    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
        PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
        PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
        BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
        BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
        0,                        // client time-out 
        NULL);                    // default security attribute 

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds, 
    // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
    // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED. 

    fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ?
        TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

    if (fConnected)
    {
        printf("Client connected, creating a processing thread.\n");

        // Create a thread for this client. 
        hThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,              // no security attribute 
            0,                 // default stack size 
            InstanceThread,    // thread proc
            (LPVOID)hPipe,    // thread parameter 
            0,                 // not suspended 
            &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 

        if (hThread == NULL)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
        else CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    else
        // The client could not connect, so close the pipe. 
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
}

DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
// This routine is a thread processing function to read from and reply to a client
// via the open pipe connection passed from the main loop. Note this allows
// the main loop to continue executing, potentially creating more threads of
// of this procedure to run concurrently, depending on the number of incoming
// client connections.
{
    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
    TCHAR* pchRequest = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR));
    TCHAR* pchReply = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR));

    DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hPipe = NULL;

    // Print verbose messages. In production code, this should be for debugging only.
    printf("InstanceThread created, receiving and processing messages.\n");

    // The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance. 

    hPipe = (HANDLE)lpvParam;

    // Loop until done reading
    while (1)
    {
        // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
        // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
        fSuccess = ReadFile(
            hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
            pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data 
            BUFSIZE,    // size of buffer 
            &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read 
            NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

        // Process the incoming message.
        _tprintf(TEXT("Client Request String:\"%s\"\n"), pchRequest);
    }

    FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);

    printf("InstanceThread exitting.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

P.S. If is some how possible to use a debugger with a injectable DLL please let me know!

Comment: There is a nasty bug in this snippet that always causes random output, the string you read is not zero-terminated.  It never will be in the Debug build and that does produce question marks on a console.  A lot of them with such a big buffer.  Consider to send strlen(write_buffer) + 1.

Comment: @HansPassant And lots more besides.  I did fix that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code, which I will come to at the end.  First, some code that works.  Please note that I have simplified things slightly by making it all into a single application (so that I could easily test it) and by getting rid of the thread, but none of that matters in the context of your question.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE     1024*1024

const TCHAR* lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\listen");
char write_buffer [BUFSIZE];

HANDLE init()
{
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile(
        lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
        GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,              // no sharing 
        NULL,           // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
        0,              // default attributes 
        NULL);          // no template file 

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf ("CreateFile returned error %d\n", GetLastError ());
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

// The pipe connected; change to message-read mode. 

    DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
    BOOL fSuccess = SetNamedPipeHandleState(
        hPipe,    // pipe handle 
        &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
        NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
        NULL);    // don't set maximum time 

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        printf ("SetNamedPipeHandleState returned error %d\n", GetLastError ());
        CloseHandle (hPipe);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

   return hPipe;    
}

void report(HANDLE hPipe, const char *frmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, frmt);
    _vsnprintf(write_buffer, BUFSIZE, frmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    // Send a message to the pipe server. 

    DWORD cbWritten;
    BOOL fSuccess = WriteFile(
        hPipe,                              // pipe handle 
        write_buffer,                       // message 
        (DWORD) strlen (write_buffer) + 1,  // message length, including EOS
        &cbWritten,                         // bytes written 
        NULL);                              // not overlapped 

    if (!fSuccess)
        printf ("WriteFile returned error %d\n", GetLastError ());
}

int _tmain (int argc, TCHAR **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1 && _tcscmp (argv [1], __T ("send")) == 0)
    {
        // send
        HANDLE hPipe = init ();
        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            report (hPipe, "A message to you, Rudi");
            CloseHandle (hPipe);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // receive
    for (;;)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n"), lpszPipename);
        HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
            lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
            PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
            BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
            BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
            0,                        // client time-out 
            NULL);                    // default security attribute 

        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf ("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }

        // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds, 
        // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
        // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED. 

        BOOL fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ?
            TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

        if (!fConnected)
        {
             printf ("Error %d connecting named pipe\n", GetLastError());
             return 255;
        }

        printf ("Client connected\n");
        HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
        char* pchRequest = (char*) HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE);

        // Loop until done reading
        while (1)
        {
            // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
            // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
            DWORD cbBytesRead = 0;
            BOOL fSuccess = ReadFile(
                hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
                pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data 
                BUFSIZE,    // size of buffer 
                &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read 
                NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

            if (!fSuccess)
                break;

            // Process the incoming message.
            printf("Client Request String:\"%s\"\n", pchRequest);
        }

        FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
        HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To run this in "send" mode, specify `send` on the command line.  Otherwise it runs as a server.  My server runs for ever.  Kill it with Ctrl+C.

So what was wrong with your code?  Well, mostly, it was a bit of a mishmash of ANSI and UNICODE strings.  You need to be much more careful with this kind of thing and you also need to calculate buffer sizes appropriately.  This is all fixed in the above code, which is why I posted it.  Also, in terms of good programming practise:

- You should check for errors much more thoroughly.
- As written, the server assumes that the string sent to it is NUL-terminated but the client doesn't send it that way (so I fixed the client).
- The server needs to break out of its receive loop when the sender closes its end of the pipe.
- Declare local variables locally! (And pass them around as parameters, when appropriate.)  Don't use unnecessary globals.
- Using #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS is better than explicitly disabling the warning that you get if you don't.

My code fixes all of these issues.  HTH.

Comment: I'll have to look at it later today to decide if it's the answer though.

Comment: OK, cool, I wonder who did, sorry I slagged you off.  Anyway, take your time, I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I am still a little confused: 1) where in your code do you specify that you are sending / receiving ANSI / UNICODE ? Is it the _ before _vsnprintf ? That and adding the EOS character seem to be the only real differences!

Comment: You were correct, it was ANSI fighting with UNICODE. I fixed my code by changing the string types to just "char*" Also, thanks for pointing out the EOS problem!

Comment: Great stuff, glad you're up and running and TU for votes.  A lesson for the future there, I hope.